# Fluent NHibernate - Configure Oracle Data Provider ODP

Tags: oracle, configuration, fluent-nhibernate, odp.net

I am brand new to NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate and I am trying to get the following confguration to work.

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
     return Fluently.Configure() 
       .Database(
       OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString("Data Source=mysource;User ID=myid;Password=mypwd;")                  
          )
         .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
         .BuildSessionFactory();

    }
```

I have the Oracle.DataAccess assembly referenced. I am using VS 2010 and .Net 4

I get the following exception :

FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException was unhandled
  Message=An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

Source=FluentNHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 98
       at HibernateLearning.Program.CreateSessionFactory() in C:\Projects\CPS Test Concepts\Main\Source\CPSTestConcepts\Source\HibernateLearning\Program.cs:line 48
       at HibernateLearning.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\CPS Test Concepts\Main\Source\CPSTestConcepts\Source\HibernateLearning\Program.cs:line 21
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: NHibernate.HibernateException
       Message=Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.
       Source=NHibernate
       StackTrace:
            at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
            at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
            at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
            at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
            at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
            at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
            at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 93
       InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
            Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
                 at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
                 at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
                 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
                 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
                 at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
                 at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
            InnerException: NHibernate.HibernateException
                 Message=The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly Oracle.DataAccess could not be found. Ensure that the assembly Oracle.DataAccess is located in the application directory or in the Global Assembly Cache. If the assembly is in the GAC, use  element in the application configuration file to specify the full name of the assembly.
                 Source=NHibernate
                 StackTrace:
                      at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName)
                      at NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver..ctor()
                 InnerException:

Comment: I clicked it by mistake. Sorry. How do I remove the wiki flag?

Comment: You can't. You can only delete and repost. It's not a big deal, you just won't get any reputation points if it's upvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. When you reference the ODP you have to set the the copy local property of the reference to true otherwise it won't find the objects it is looking for.

One hurdle down, I'm sure there will be more but I am loving these tools!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You might also get this problem if you have a mismatch between the platforms of the ODP dll and the platform of your application (x86 vs x64).  Change your project to compile against the correct platform.